# Android questions about communicating between devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-nearby

Here is my problem: I have three or more Android devices which need to communicate with each other. They are always in close proximity to each other, however there are a few restrictions I unfortunately have.

1. The devices have no connection to the internet, so web sockets is not an option.
2. A device needs to be able to connect to at least two or more devices .
3. The devices will be on battery, so the communication should be as power efficient as possible.

Fortunately I only need to support API 19 and over. Now for a little more detail. Basically think of McDonalds, the registers in the front get an input, which is then send to oder devices in the back in the kitchen to tell the cooks what food needs to be prepared. I'm trying to achieve a similar thing with tablets. So one or more devices serve as the register which receive user input. these devices should then send data to the other tablets (or a singe tablet if that is easier) in the back. So these devices should connect to each other at the beginning, and then over the next 6 to 8 hours send anywhere from 0 to 300 messages an hour based on user input.

Here is what I found so far:

I started looking into the default [`BluetoothManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager) for this, which would logically be the first idea. However regular bluetooth can consume a lot of power, and didn't seem very efficient, especially since it could happen, that no data at all needs to be transferred for an hour. (The frequency is unpredictable).

I then continued my search and the next thing I found was [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le). It seemed way more promising than regular bluetooth, however I read a lot of statements, that BLE is not very stable. And I struggled to find good resources which I need to better understand BLE and how to use it in android. Furthermore the resources I found only focused on how to connect to Bluetooth Low Energy preipherals, like fitness trackers, and I haven't found a single thing on how to expose an own GATT server in android, so a different android device can connect to it.

So I looked for alternatives and stumbled upon the [Nearby Connections API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) in the Google Play Services, which too looks very promising. However I am not sure about power consumtion, since the API primises high bandwidth and performance, which is not necessarily my #1 priority. However it also says

> Under the hood, the API uses a combination of Bluetooth, BLE, and Wifi hotspots, leveraging the strengths of each while circumventing their respective weaknesses.

which as I understand means, that it can fall back on non-power-intensive communication method?

So here are all the questions I have:

- Are there any good resources on creating a BLE preipheral on android?
- Is BLE really as unstable as I read or have there been improvements, or were those statements just wrong?
- How is the power consumption for Nearby Connections? And does it go down to a minimum when no data is transferred?
- Are there any other ways to implement this M:N communication?

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

Nearby Connections exists so you don't have to worry about figuring out how to use the radio APIs on Android, much less how make them work across multiple versions of Android. :)

After working on Nearby Connections for ~3 years, I can attest that BLE is indeed a nightmare to work with.

The high-power operation (for both, Bluetooth Classic and BLE) is scanning -- as long as you don't scan all the time, just keeping a connection established has negligible power consumption.

I highly encourage you to give [Nearby Connections with P2P_CLUSTER](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/strategies#p2p_cluster) a try -- we built it exactly for M:N use-cases like yours.

P.S. And [@virhonestum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2852578/virhonestum), Nearby Connections is a fully-offline API, and doesn't at all need a connection to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

BLE is a decent platform, but might not be the most efficient and predictable setup for what you are doing.

Basically the beaconing device (register) would put together a very small packet of information and send it out once every second while a different device scans for the packets. The beaconing is the easy part, but scanning can be tricky and use more battery.

The struggle though would be building custom packets to do it since most beacons usually broadcast urls or numbers relating to a database, Nearby also requires an internet connection to work and only picks an activity up on screen events or by manual scanning, but BLE beacons don't need internet connections to be picked up. Android Beacon Library is usually the easiest way to implement it if these aren't major concerns.

I would try doing some sort of adhoc wifi connection if your devices have WiFi built in.

Comment: Nearby does not require an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the devices have no connection to the internet so web sockets are not an option, but if they are connected to a local network you can still use sockets to communicate between instances of your app.

I'm not sure if this is a possibility for your app, but you can find an example of how to do this here: http://brendaninnis.ca/connect-nearby-devices-part-2.html